# Creating a service that accepts no arguments

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a service that accepts no arguments and returns a string.
My attempt in srv file was

```
---     
string return_value
```

The node that implements the service looks like this

```
from testService.srv import NoArguments
import rospy

def service_implementation():
    return "answer"

if __name__=="__main__":
    rospy.init_node('service_node')
    s = rospy.Service('service_with_no_arguments', NoArguments, service_implementation)
    rospy.spin()
```

However, when I try to call it, I get an error:

> error processing request:
> service_implementation() takes no
> arguments (1 given)

What would be the right way to define a service that accepts no arguments?

EDIT: I noticed that one way to do it would be to add (some) argument to service_implementation so that it looks like

```
def service_implementation(request):
        return "answer"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242296/creating-a-service-that-accepts-no-arguments/) by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 526 on 2016-08-24

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> --- string return_value
> ```

The basic approach seems ok, but I'd add a new-line between the `---` and your `string return_value`, like so:

```
---
string return_value
```

You write:

> However, when I try to call it, I get an error that function accepted 0 arguments and got 1

Could you please add a snippet to your question that shows exactly what you're trying to do, and what the exact error message is?

---

Edit:

> EDIT: I noticed that one way to do it would be to add (some) argument to service_implementation so that it looks like

> ```
> def service_implementation(request):
> ```

```
        return "answer"
```

Ah, yes.

When talking about 'services', we (I ?) always think of the abstracted ROS API level. So a 'no arguments service' is a ROS service that takes no arguments (like you defined), but at the C++/Python implementation level, you'll always need to accept (and handle) the request-reply pair that gets supplied by the ROS middleware to your client program.

For a 'no arguments service', that will just mean that the `Request` type has no (public) member fields. In Python, returning just a `str` probably then works because it's automatically transformed using the appropriate constructor of the `Reply` type.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-08-24**:
I edited the question. While doing it, I understood that one solution would be adding the argument to service_implementation function (and then ignoring it). that would be - it is not without arguments, but with an empty argument.
If you have additional comments, please add.

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-08-24**:
the new line issue was a formatting problem